# JSF - App design issue. How to get data in backing bean A, after user logs in to backing bean B

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to load some data after a user logs in to my app. I need the username to load data specific to the user. The problem I'm having is that I have a `SessionScoped` backing bean that contains the code to log the user in, and then I have a `ViewScoped` page specific backing bean (which injects the SessionScoped bean) which is to load the data for the page.

Currently this is the code that I have and I get a null pointer when loading the data because the username doesn't exist when the `loadData()` method is called.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a solution to this problem as I'd like to NOT have to put the login dialog on every page and keep it in the template.xhtml file if possible.

template.xhtml

```xml
...
<!-- Login Dialog -->
    <p:dialog id="loginDialog" header="Login" widgetVar="loginWidget" modal="true" visible="#{!accessBacking.hasAccess}" closable="false">
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <p:messages id="loginFormMessages" severity="error" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="10" width="300">  

            <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />  
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{accessBacking.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Username is Required" />

            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />  
            <p:password id="password" value="#{accessBacking.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Password is Required" />

            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{accessBacking.checkViewAccess}" oncomplete="handleAuthenticationRequest(xhr, status, args)" update="loginFormMessages" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid> 
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
...
```

userGroups.xhtml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{userGroupBacking.setCurrentMenu}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userGroupBacking.users}" editable="true" id="userTable">
...
```

AccessBacking.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="accessBacking")
@SessionScoped
public class AccessBacking {
        private String username;
    private String password;

    public boolean checkViewAccess() {
        Access access = new Access();
        if(access.authenticate(username, password)) {
          // user is logged in  
        }
    }
}
```

UserGroupBacking

```
@ManagedBean(name="userGroupBacking")
@ViewScoped
public class UserGroupBacking {

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{accessBacking}")
    private AccessBacking accessBacking;
    public void setAccessBacking(AccessBacking accessBacking) {
        this.accessBacking = accessBacking;
    }

        @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        loadData();
    }

        /**
     * Loads the data for the page
     */
    public void loadData() {
        Dao dao = new Dao(ds);
        users = dao.findAllUsers(accessBacking.getUsername(), accessBacking.getRoles());  // NULL POINTER BECAUSE ACCESSBACKING.GETUSERNAME() IS NULL SINCE THE USER HASN'T LOGGED IN YET.
    }
}
```

Comment: How about triggering `UserGroupBacking#loadData()` in `AccessBacking#checkViewAccess()` inside if-statement that confirms successfull login? Before just initialize `UserGroupBacking`'s `users` (which seems to be a `Collection`) to a new (and empty) `Collection`?

Comment: Is it `username` the variable which is null or the whole `accessBacking` bean which doesn't get injected? If the first one, makes sense, you can't load the data about a user without having him logged in.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker - I believe it's the first one. I know that makes sense, but i'm looking for a solution.

Comment: @Lester I can't do that because UserGroupBacking is not injected into AccessBacking, but it's the other way around.

Comment: That's then your own design problem. The fastest solution here is not to allow loading the data till the user logs in (it's the rational step).

Comment: That's obviously what needs to be done. One solution I have is to move the login dialog from the template.xhtml to every single page I have and then have that login dialog's actionListener go to the page specific bean which would call the accessBacking bean to check the access and then load the data. Ideally, I'd like to keep 1 login dialog in the template.xhtml rather than copying and pasting that dialog into every .xhtml page.

Comment: You can keep the login dialog into the template. Just check the user is logged in before loading data which needs user credentials. Appart from that, at view side, also check the components which needs user to be logged in are not `rendered` if user is not inside. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the original problem. Please see my answer to see if it helps you understand the problem I was having. Basically I couldn't trigger the userGroupBacking#loadData() method from my accessBacking bean which is where the login handler existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a good solution by using `ui:param`. Basically I set a `ui:param` with my backing bean value in my page specific xhtml and then reference that `ui:param` in my template.

Updated code from question with new solution:

template.xhtml

```
...
<!-- NOTE the 'myBacking' instead of the 'userGroupBacking' -->
<!-- Login Dialog -->
    <p:dialog id="loginDialog" header="Login" widgetVar="loginWidget" modal="true" visible="#{!myBacking.hasAccess}" closable="false">
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <p:messages id="loginFormMessages" severity="error" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="10" width="300">  

            <p:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />  
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{accessBacking.username}" required="true" requiredMessage="Username is Required" />

            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />  
            <p:password id="password" value="#{accessBacking.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Password is Required" />

            <h:panelGroup></h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{myBacking.checkViewAccess}" oncomplete="handleAuthenticationRequest(xhr, status, args)" update="loginFormMessages" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid> 
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
...
```

userGroups.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{userGroupBacking.setCurrentMenu}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <!-- THIS IS PART OF THE SOLUTION -->
    <ui:param name="myBacking" value="#{userGroupBacking}" />

    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userGroupBacking.users}" editable="true" id="userTable">
...
```

AccessBacking.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="accessBacking")
@SessionScoped
public class AccessBacking {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public boolean checkViewAccess() {
        Access access = new Access();
        if(access.authenticate(username, password)) {
          // user is logged in  
        }
    }
}
```

UserGroupBacking

```
@ManagedBean(name="userGroupBacking")
@ViewScoped
public class UserGroupBacking {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{accessBacking}")
    private AccessBacking accessBacking;
    public void setAccessBacking(AccessBacking accessBacking) {
        this.accessBacking = accessBacking;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        loadData();
    }

    // CHECKS AGAINST ACCESSBACKING
    public boolean isHasAccess() {
    return accessBacking.isHasAccess();
    }

    // CHECKS AGAINST ACCESSBACKING
    public boolean checkViewAccess() {
    return accessBacking.checkViewAccess();
    }

    /**
     * Loads the data for the page
     */
    public void loadData() {
        Dao dao = new Dao(ds);
        users = dao.findAllUsers(accessBacking.getUsername(), accessBacking.getRoles());  
    }
}
```

Comment: It's something similar to the workaround I've purposed on my last comment. By the way, you're assigning a `ui:param` of the bean's reference to be used later, why don't you use bean's reference itself? You're also using the `@ViewScoped` bean as kind of intermediary between the view and `AccessBacking` class. Just use `accessBacking` as reference from the view page. Isn't it a managed bean? Take advantage of it!

Comment: I'm using the ui:param because I have multiple pages all with their own viewscoped backing beans. The accessBacking bean is a sessionscoped bean that I want to handle the login so i only need 1 login dialog in the template.